# Schedule USB Eject After File Transfer

Tags: usb, file-transfer, scheduled-tasks, safely-remove-hardware

There are times I want to schedule a USB to eject once files finish transferring, e.g. when I don't want to stay around to wait for the transfer and the person who needs the USB doesn't have access to the computer.

Is there any way I can "Safely Remove" this USB automatically only once file transfers have completed?

Comment: What OS you are using? If you are using Windows, you can try Removedrive.exe http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html

Answer (score 0):

If you format the usb as NTFS, you can configure it for quick removal so that it won't corrupt when pulled out. Does that meet your needs?